# Label displaying "Optional('#') in Swift when using NumberFormatter

Tags: swift3, numberformatter

I have the following code:

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
let formattedNumber = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: rawValue))

currentLogBF.text = "\(formattedNumber) BF"
```

In the above example, rawValue is a Double that is calculated when all of the input fields have values in them.

currentLogBF is a label in my View.

Whenever a calculation is completed, the label displays something like this:

```
Optional("12,307.01") BF
```

How do I get rid of the "Optional()" piece, so it just displays this:

```
12,307.01 BF
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You have to unwrap your optional before String Interpolation

Answer (score 0):

The function `numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber)` will return you a String Optional (String?) instead of String.
You will need to unwrap it first like this

```
if let formattedNumber = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: rawValue)) {
    currentLogBF.text = "\(formattedNumber) BF"
} else {
    Log.warn("Failed to format number!")
}
```

And as bonus, use `String(format: "%@ BF", formattedNumber)` rather than `"\(formattedNumber) BF"` when dealing with optional.
String(format:) will give you compile error when you try to pass optional value as an argument

Answer (score 0):

unwrapping an optional value

```
let formattedNumber:String? = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: rawValue))

currentLogBF.text = "\(formattedNumber!) BF" //optional string. This will result in nil while unwrapping an optional value if value is not initialized or if initialized to nil.

currentLogBF.text = "\(formattedNumber) BF" //Optional("optional string") //nil values are handled in this statement
```